# What version of Android Studio to use with Androidx (Android Jetpack) Source Code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Following these instructions [how to download android jetpack code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/README.md).

I have an observation to make and a question to post.

Observation: Make sure you have 20 GB available at the bare minimum. I expected it to be around 6 GB (as mentioned in the instructions - *"Now your repository is set to pull only what you need for building and running AndroidX libraries. Download the code (and grab a coffee while we pull down 6GB*" - turned out to be a **whopping 17 GB**;

[image]

I don't have a lot of space on my Mac, so had to clean up and that was not enough. Cleaned up more, finally was able to download the full code. But that's not the end of disk space problems.

Proceeded to step

[image: open project]

This started downloading AS 3.6 preview - another bunch of GB that I don't have!!!

I already have AS 3.5 and 4 - I understand that 3.6 is the *recommended* version - but anyone had experience using 3.5 or 4 with that code? I really don't want yet another version eating up all that is left of my disk space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you must use the version of Android Studio that `./studiow` uses.

AndroidX only moves to newer versions of Studio when they start using new functionality in that version, so using an older version of Studio would not work.

Comment: thanks, but your answer is a bit confusing. The recommended version is 3.6 The "newer" version in that case would be 4 correct? So androidx hasn't moved there and ok then, can't use 4.  But how does it make 3.5 not usable here? Or do you mean to say that its using something that is specific to 3.6, which is not available in 3.5 and somehow not available in 4 either?

Comment: The default case is using the latest stable Studio. The only reason AndroidX wouldn't be using the latest stable Studio is because it requires a newer version - specifically, functionality in 3.6. While Android Studio allows you to use stable versions of the Android Gradle Plugin with newer versions of Studio, you can't use non-stable versions of Android Gradle Plugin (like the 3.6 version that AndroidX uses) with Studio 4.0 or anything but the exact version of Studio that matches the version of Android Gradle Plugin.

Comment: ok thanks for the quick response - you guys might want to update your download instructions to reflect that (as well adjust the expected download size - you say 6 GB, but it's 17 now) - and thanks again, all clear now

Comment: You could put in a change request to the README :)

Comment: will gladly do so, but where is the readme? Or do you mean issue tracker - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192731&template=842428?

Comment: You linked to the README in your question, it is a file in the repository and part of your checkout.

Comment: some parts fail to build - for example, Lifecycle - Task :lifecycle:lifecycle-process:lint FAILED
/Users/dmitri/frameworks/support/lifecycle/lifecycle-process/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner.java:171: Error: Call requires API level Q (current min is 14): android.app.Activity#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks [NewApi]
                activity.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new EmptyActivityLifecycleCallbacks() { I didn't not modify anything. Is the code we pull guaranteed to be buildable?